# Want to selected dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have one table from I fetch the country and in another table I have a selected value. In AJAX success, I am getting all the countries and selected value also.

I want a condition in the dropdown where the selected value need to shows up in edit view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="required">Country</label>
    <select id="country-dropdown" name="country" class="form-control form_input required"></select>            
</div>

var countryoption = "";
$.each(data.countries, function(index, value) {
    selectedVal = data.country_id;
    countryoption += "<option value='" + value.id + "'>" + value.countryname + "</option>";
});
$('#country-dropdown').html(countryoption);
```

Using `$.each`, all the countries get set, but I want show in edit form the selected value (`selectedVal`).

I am not getting exact condition.  Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```js
isSelected = selectedVal == value.id ? 'selected' : '';
countryoption += "<option value='" + value.id + "' " + isSelected + ">" + value.countryname + "</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `selected` attribute on `option` to show it selected in the form.

```
var countryoption = "";
$.each(data.countries, function(index, value) {
    selectedVal = data.country_id;
    countryoption += "<option value='" + value.id + "'";
    if(selectedVal && selectedVal.trim()!='') {
      countryoption += " selected ";
    }
    countryoption +=  ">" + value.countryname + "</option>";
});
$('#country-dropdown').html(countryoption);
```